# Translational invariance and zero eigenvalue

Tags: linear-algebra, reference-request, operator-theory, dynamical-systems, nonlinear-system

Page 2 (506), line 18 of
http://www-personal.umich.edu/~orosz/articles/NonlinScipublished.pdf

says that "The presence of translational symmetry in the nonlinear equations gives rise to a relevant zero eigenvalue in the linearized system at any of the trivial solutions".

It looks like a general statement, but I don't see why (is it trivial?). Where can I find a precise statement about this and on what conditions does that hold? (I'd like to know the proof too.) Thank you.

Comment: I'm not recollecting the details well enough to make an answer, but there's a clue in the abstract: "The Jacobian belonging to the equilibrium of the corresponding delay-differential equations always has a zero eigenvalue due to the translational symmetry." So evidently the Jacobian is the key object in the story.